# Google Play store cancels every subscription

Tags: in-app-purchase, google-play-services

If a user subscribes in-app, it is always refunded exactly three days later. Like this:

[image]

Intended behaviour is for the subscription to remain activated and payment not to be refunded.

Why might this happen?

Answer (score 1):

Google has updated its In-App payment policies a while back and you'd need to acknowledge the payment within three days in order to retain the payment. Otherwise, your payment would get automatically refunded.

There is a new `acknowledge()` method available so you'd need to acknowledge your purchase.

Google states that the acknowledgement should only place after processing and granting the said features that come with In-App purchase.

See more information here.

> If you do not acknowledge a purchase within three days, the user automatically receives a refund, and Google Play revokes the purchase.

https://developer.android.com/google/play/billing/billing_library_releases_notes#release-2_0

Comment: @paperjam were you able to solve your problem based on this feedback?